# Is there an issue with simultaneously querying a database with two queries?

Tags: swift, database

I have a database where I store information (no really?) and I use the DB to append a set of arrays during the `viewDidLoad()` of the initial `ViewController`. I would like to run the query/appending every time the page loads, which is why it is in the `viewDidLoad()` It works fine. Generally:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let vDLQuery = PFQuery(className: "classA")
    vDLQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        for object in objects?{
            //append a set of arrays
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine. My question is, can I query the same DB/class in the `didFinishLaunching()` without there being issues? I would like to append a different set of arrays only upon the first launch of the app (and not during every load of the first view, as with the first query), but this query pulls from the same DB/class:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "classA")
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
       for object in objects{
          //append a different set of arrays
       }
    }
}
```

Since the viewController with the `vDLQuery` in question is the first controller, these two queries will probably be run around the same time. My question is, will this cause an issue as they are appending different arrays at the same time from the same class of the database?

Comment: Not familiar with the db in question but in general if you want to concurrent queries you can use two different connections to the same database. If there's only ever one connection available, you _probably_ have to perform the queries serially (wait for the first to return before sending another one).

Comment: @hasen I mean the database allows for this (its parse-server hosted by heroku), as I can get the desired result for the arrays every time, but I am just wondering if it has any potential negative effects.

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems there's a global function that takes some input to perform a query. I think it's reasonable to assume that internally the function creates a new connection each time it's called, so it's _probably_ safe.